# iOS game center Is it possible to change user's top score in the game server?

Tags: ios, game-center

The server updates all users' new scores, but the game center score top list doesn't change at the same time. Users must be playing the game, and commit the new score in the app.

Is it possible to change user's top score in the server, instead of committing it by the app?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, and I'm guessing it *isn't* possible, but I'm curious to see if anyone's figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

To update scores in Game Center you have to commit the new scores to the leaderboard each time. You have to wait around 20 minutes for the list to update after each new entry is submitted to the leaderboard ("scores may take up to 20 minutes to appear"). To manually remove entries from the list go to your app in iTunes Connect and go to the manage Game Center section.